# Factor of 1/2 in the cross section of Møller scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, scattering-cross-section, identical-particles

I have seen everywhere (like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8ller_scattering)) that in
Møller scattering the cross section is calculated with the formula:

$$\frac{\mathrm d \sigma}{\mathrm d \Omega} = \frac{1}{64 \pi^2 E_{CM}^2 } \frac{|\pmb{p}_i|}{|\pmb{p}_f|} \overline{|M_{fi}|}^2 $$

But shouldn't there be an extra factor of $\frac{1}{2} $ due to indistinguishableness of the final two electrons? This should change the formula to:

$$\frac{\mathrm d \sigma}{\mathrm d \Omega} = \frac{1}{128 \pi^2 E_{CM}^2 } \frac{|\pmb{p}_i|}{|\pmb{p}_f|} \overline{|M_{fi}|}^2 $$

Why isn't this accounted for?

Comment: Have you followed a derivation in a textbook?

Comment: @DanielC not really. I saw how the cross section is derived in a general case (and all textbooks have as end results the first formula: $\frac{1}{64 \pi^2 E_{CM}^2}...$ but at the same time make very clear that there should be and extra $\frac{1}{2} $ if the outgoing particles were identical. In the case of Moller scattering Wikipedia and the other online source I found (who probably just copied/pasted from Wikipedia) didn't write this extra factor and that made me wonder why.

Comment: @SG8 Well, that factor has nothing to do with the amplitude. It comes from performing the integration over the momenta of the two outgoing particles, and then since they are identical the actual phase space is to be reduced by half

Answer (score 2):

The indistinguishable particle factor is handled in $\overline{|M_{fi}|^2}$. (Note that the square goes under the over-bar).

There are two separate diagrams at tree level. The $t$-channel process:

$$ e^-_1e^-_2 \rightarrow e^-_3e^-_4$$
[image]

and the $u$-channel, describing the crossed final state:

$$ e^-_1e^-_2 \rightarrow e^-_4e^-_3$$

[image]

They add coherently, with a minus sign in-front of the crossed-channel:

$$iM_{fi} = i(M_t - M_u)$$

$$M_{fi}=-i(-ie)^2\big[
\frac 1 t\bar u(p_3)\gamma^{\mu}u(p_1)\bar u(p_4)\gamma_{\mu}u(p_2)-
\frac 1 u\bar u(p_3)\gamma^{\mu}u(p_2)\bar u(p_4)\gamma_{\mu}u(p_1)
\big]$$

You then square that and take the appropriate traces, which sums over the initial and final spin states. Hence, you need to divide by 4 in order to average over the initial spin states (unless your beam/target is/are polarized):

$$\overline{|M_{fi}|^2}=\frac 1 4 \sum_{\rm spins}|M_{fi}|^2 $$
$$=2e^4\big[\frac 1 {t^2}(s^2+u^2-8m^2(s+u)+24m^4)+
\frac 1{u^2}(s^2+t^2-8m^2(s+t)+24m^4)
+\frac 2{tu}(s^2-8m^2s+12m^4)\big]$$

So the $1/t^2$ term is from $t$-channel scatterings, and the $1/u^2$ term is exchanged final state. The $1/{tu}$ term is from interference between the two amplitudes. Clearly, it's not just a factor of $1/2$.

From there, you transform to the lab frame:

$$\frac{\mathrm d \sigma}{\mathrm d \Omega} = \frac{1}{64 \pi^2 E_{CM}^2 } \frac{|\pmb{p}_i|}{|\pmb{p}_f|} \overline{|M_{fi}|^2} $$

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not see how we have counted the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in the amplitude. Peskin on page 108, at the end of section 5 of chapter 4 seems to make it clear that the amplitude and the extra factor 1/2 are in no way connected

Comment: This factor 1/2 is also taken into account by Peskin in formula 4.100 in a $\phi^4$ theory